# How to fix kaa errer Check the logs after startup

Tags: java, open-source, iot, platform, kaa

I follow step by step when installing kaa single node but I have an error in  heck the logs after startup.----> cat /var/log/kaa/* | grep ERROR

this is the error:

```
2019-01-31 14:14:34,956 [main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
2019-01-31 14:14:34,961 [main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
2019-01-31 14:14:37,769 [main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
2019-01-31 14:14:37,773 [main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
2019-01-31 14:14:37,897 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (No active connection found for master : Could not connect to HostAddress{host='localhost', port=3306, type='master'}.Connection refused (Connection refused))
2019-01-31 14:14:37,910 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
2019-01-31 14:30:23,673 [main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
2019-01-31 14:30:23,678 [main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
2019-01-31 14:30:27,142 [main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
2019-01-31 14:30:27,146 [main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
2019-01-31 14:30:27,266 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (No active connection found for master : Could not connect to HostAddress{host='localhost', port=3306, type='master'}.Connection refused (Connection refused))
2019-01-31 14:30:27,279 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
2019-01-31 22:34:01,662 [main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
2019-01-31 22:34:01,667 [main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
2019-01-31 22:34:04,979 [main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
2019-01-31 22:34:04,983 [main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
2019-01-31 22:34:05,115 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (No active connection found for master : Could not connect to HostAddress{host='localhost', port=3306, type='master'}.Connection refused (Connection refused))
2019-01-31 22:34:05,128 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed and configured correctly MaridDB? Port 3306 is default port for MySQL/MariaDB connection.

Here correct steps:

1. Install MariaDB (sudo apt install mariadb*)
2. mysql -u root -p
3. CREATE USER 'sqladmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'admin'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sqladmin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
4. CREATE DATABASE kaa
   CHARACTER SET utf8
   COLLATE utf8_general_ci;